# Passing a CancellationToken through a URI in C#

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, http-get, cancellation-token

I have a currently working controller method like the following in one project:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetReport([FromUri] ReportParamiters ReportRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{…}
```

But this may be called from another project using the following to make a pass-through call, dependant on who/where the caller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetReport([FromUri] ReportParameters ReportParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        using(HttpClient client = this.MessageTransferHelper.BuildJsonHttpClient(Helper.BearerToken(this.Url.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString())))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response =
                    await
                        client.GetAsync(this.ConfigurationService.ReportsUrl() + "report1/?DateFrom=" +
                                        ReportParameters.DateFrom.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "&DateTo=" + ReportParameters.DateTo.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") +
                                        "&valueList=" + String.Join("&valueList=", ReportParameters.Stores.ToArray()));
                return response;
```

The second example simply creates the url and passes it to the actual controller held in the first example, and returns the results. I've searched Google for an answer to this, but can't find anything that matches.

Can I create a cancellation token passed into the GET of the second example, as shown, and then pass it on (along with the relevant search information) into the other GET ? (which is running on another, remote, server)

Comment: In the world of webAPI there is a request and a response and that is it. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the cancelation token here as that would only be used internally. You couldn't make the request to this method and then use the token during the request to stop the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly [pass a `CancellationToken` to `GetAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551747.aspx). It won't be the *same* cancellation token as the remote server will get, but they will be logically connected.

The `CancellationToken` in the remote `GetReport` may(1) be triggered if the calling process closes the HTTP socket. The local `GetReport` can pass a `CancellationToken` to `HttpClient`, which would cause it to cancel the request by closing its socket. If the local `GetReport` passes on the `CancellationToken` that it gets, then the following should(1) happen:

- If the caller of the local `GetReport` (i.e., an end-user browser) cancels its request (i.e., user closes the browser tab), then the local `GetReport`'s `CancellationToken` is(1) canceled.
- This causes the `HttpClient` to cancel its request.
- This causes(1) the remote `GetReport`'s `CancellationToken` to cancel.

(1) It *should* be cancelled in theory. In reality, there's a rat's nest of bugs in ASP.NET cancellation, with the end result that the cancellation is not really *guaranteed* to happen. I expect this will be fixed in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: So this: await
                            client.GetAsync(this.ConfigurationService.ReportsUrl() + "vatreport1/departments/?DateFrom=" +
                                            vatReportParameters.DateFrom.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "&DateTo=" + vatReportParameters.DateTo.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") +
                                            "&stores=" + String.Join("&stores=", vatReportParameters.Stores.ToArray()), cancellationToken);

Comment: So adding the cancellationToken to the GetAsync  would link these, but the token in the remote (called) process would still be generated locally.  Thanks.